# flask app - how to interactively select image path from template?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, leaflet, jinja2

I have large image collections on my local NAS (microscopy images of cultured cells for scientific purposes). With the goal to compare subsets of images (some 10-20 at a time), I wrote a flask app that displays images on my screen and also implements synchronized zoom/pan functionality (with leaflet).

Everything works fine, but an important part is missing: a feature to switch to another subset of images e.g. by clicking a button.

The core problem: I can choose a path for an individual image (from the template containing paths) with a fixed index number, e.g.

'cdn/{{ paths[  0 ] }}'

but need a way to do this with an index variable. I tried for hours - no success.

Here are some core parts of the code.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render template

# ...

app.config['IMAGE_EXTS'] = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".tif"] 

@app.route('/')
def root():

    path_to_images = <path/to/local/NAS>

    paths = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path_to_images):
        for file in files:
            if any(file.endswith(ext) for ext in app.config['IMAGE_EXTS']):
                paths.append(encode(os.path.join(root,file)))
    # ...
    
    return render_template('index.html', paths=paths)
```

index.html

```
//... loading several images - this works with fixed index numbers but I need a way to choose paths with an index variable

        L.imageOverlay('cdn/{{ paths[  0 ] }}' , bounds).addTo(map0);
        L.imageOverlay('cdn/{{ paths[  1 ] }}' , bounds).addTo(map1);
        L.imageOverlay('cdn/{{ paths[  2 ] }}' , bounds).addTo(map2);
        L.imageOverlay('cdn/{{ paths[  3 ] }}' , bounds).addTo(map3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution - maybe not elegant but simple and efficient.

In `index.html`, I transform template paths

```
var p = '{{paths | tojson | safe}}'
// p is string of format '["a0882030", "b030450203", "c2002340", ...]'
// p is easily transformed into array p_arr ['a0882030', 'b030450203', 'c2002340', ...]
```

Elements of `p_arr` (which are image paths in a format that I do not understand) can then be accessed by index or index variable.

This works (i.e. image is displayed):

```
var p_idx = 0
L.imageOverlay('cdn/' + p_arr[p_idx] , bounds).addTo(map0);
```